# App crash when resume from background

Tags: ios, meteor

My app sometimes crash if it has been in the background for a while and I bring it back into the foreground. I would much appreciate any help on the matter.  The log say that the crash is triggered by tread 5. It seems to have something to do with resuming the Meteor session. using a token?

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank You !

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2
Process:             MyApp [1971]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/801F312F-A114-4EBC-81B3-5DDC8AEA76BC/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:          MyApp
Version:             4 (1)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-03-30 18:59:31.31 +0200
Launch Time:         2016-03-30 18:41:24.24 +0200
OS Version:          iOS 9.0.2 (13A452)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  5

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x182464f5c __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x19705bf80 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                  0x182464e2c +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 108
3   Foundation                      0x183353f3c -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 112
4   Meteor                          0x100b3c910 -[METDDPConnection sendMessage:] (METDDPConnection.m:72)
5   Meteor                          0x100b36f18 -[METDDPClient sendMessage:] (METDDPClient.m:275)
6   Meteor                          0x100b3a40c -[METDDPClient sendMethodMessageForMethodInvocation:] (METDDPClient.m:609)
7   Meteor                          0x100b4ccb0 -[METMethodInvocation start] (METMethodInvocation.m:81)
8   Foundation                      0x183389c20 __NSOQSchedule_f + 224
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x197855770 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x19786175c _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x197859274 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x19786362c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 728
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x19786334c _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x197a69478 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x197a69028 start_wqthread + 4


Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
412.483308   CFNetwork                  0x0000000181b699a4 TCP Conn 0x12f667c10 SSL Handshake DONE
412.625113   CFNetwork                  0x0000000181b698b4 TCP Conn 0x12f667c10 starting SSL negotiation
412.625906   CFNetwork                  0x0000000181c0b760 TCP Conn 0x12f667c10 complete. fd: 6, err: 0
412.625907   CFNetwork                  0x0000000181c0cc8c TCP Conn 0x12f667c10 event 1. err: 0



Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019706da6c weak_read_no_lock + 44
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019706da60 weak_read_no_lock + 32
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000197074984 objc_loadWeakRetained + 108
3   UIKit                           0x00000001879fb6a4 -[UITextSelectionView interactionAssistant] + 24
4   UIKit                           0x0000000187a025dc -[UITextSelectionView updateSelectionRects] + 128
5   UIKit                           0x0000000187a02524 -[UITextSelectionView updateSelectionRectsIfNeeded] + 84
6   UIKit                           0x0000000187f325f4 __51-[UITextSelectionView deferredUpdateSelectionRects]_block_invoke + 36
7   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018241bc30 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
8   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001824199d4 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182419d1c __CFRunLoopRun + 696
10  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182348dc0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
11  GraphicsServices                0x000000018d49c088 GSEventRunModal + 180
12  UIKit                           0x0000000187a22f44 UIApplicationMain + 204
13  MyApp                           0x000000010016582c 0x1000b8000 + 710700
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001978868b8 start + 4

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001979a459c kevent_qos + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197868a04 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 232
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019785793c _dispatch_source_invoke + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197988c30 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197988aac mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018241c168 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182419e6c __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182348dc0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
5   Foundation                      0x00000001832bc7ec -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 308
6   PocketSocket                    0x0000000100bba2b4 -[PSWebSocketNetworkThread main] (PSWebSocketNetworkThread.m:64)
7   Foundation                      0x00000001833a3138 __NSThread__start__ + 1000
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a6bb3c _pthread_body + 156
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a6baa0 _pthread_body + 0
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a69030 thread_start + 4

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197988c30 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197988aac mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018241c168 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182419e6c __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182348dc0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000181be6074 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 412
6   Foundation                      0x00000001833a3138 __NSThread__start__ + 1000
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a6bb3c _pthread_body + 156
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a6baa0 _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a69030 thread_start + 4

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001979a3408 __select + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001824226d0 __CFSocketManager + 648
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a6bb3c _pthread_body + 156
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a6baa0 _pthread_body + 0
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a69030 thread_start + 4

Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x12f57ff00 :: login((
        {
        resume = "dLJOlefqcSP3c8jFB6J4l_ZEnN6l_5UxpAlo1gUYBas";
    }
)) (QOS
Thread 5 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001979a31e0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a6cf0c pthread_kill + 112
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000197916b78 abort + 140
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001966d93f4 __cxa_bad_cast + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001966f5e98 default_unexpected_handler() + 0
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019705c248 _objc_terminate() + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001966f2f44 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001966f2fd0 std::set_new_handler(void (*)()) + 0
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019705c1a4 _destroyAltHandlerList + 0
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197855784 _dispatch_client_callout + 36
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019786175c _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197859274 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019786362c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 728
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019786334c _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a69478 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a69028 start_wqthread + 4**

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001979a3c0c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a69538 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a69028 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001979a3c0c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a69538 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a69028 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001979a3c0c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a69538 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a69028 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001979a3c0c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a69538 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a69028 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001979a3c0c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a69538 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a69028 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001979a3c0c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a69538 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a69028 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001979a3c0c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a69538 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a69028 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001979a3c0c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a69538 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a69028 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001979a3c0c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a69538 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a69028 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001979a3c0c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a69538 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197a69028 start_wqthread + 4
```

Comment: You're trying to send a message when the connection isn't open

Comment: @dan Ok.  Is that related to this line? 5   Meteor                          0x100b36f18 -[METDDPClient sendMessage:] (METDDPClient.m:275)  Is there anyway fro me to know what initiates this call? Or why the connection is not open ?

Comment: Sure? That line is one call in the stack trace that led to the exception

Comment: @dan Sorry I have never had an issue like this before, I am really not sure what this log is telling me.  With bugs I have always been given the line# in the code and could backtrace it.  But this seems to come from the Framework Meteor itself right.  Or is it something in my code, and if so, are you able to make out where?

Comment: The exception is caused by the `assert()` on line 72 in `METDDPConnection.m` that checks that the connection is open before sending a message, so yes it's in the framework.  I don't know what Meteor is or how you are using it so I have no idea if it's a bug in the framework or it's you doing something wrong.  It's probably you though.

Comment: @dan hahaha ..yes you are probably right... ok thanks..funny